# How to Get GrandTotal in TableList/Grid in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I just want to add method in interploation for the totalamount to obtain list in tablelist/grid.

billing.component.ts

```
// Calculate sale billing Grand Amount
calculateGrandAmount(salesBillingForm: any) {
    debugger
    let totalAmt = this.calculateAmount();
    let calcGrandTot = salesBillingForm.GrandAmount.setValue((totalAmt - (salesBillingForm.Discount.value)) + ((totalAmt - (salesBillingForm.Discount.value)) * 0.13));
    return ((calcGrandTot)).toFixed(2);
}
```

billing.component.html

```
<tbody *ngFor="let row of SalesBilling">
<tr style="background:#eceaea">
    <td align="right">{{row.NetAmount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td align="right">{{row.VATAmount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td align="right">{{row.GrandAmount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <!-- <td align="right">{{calculateGrandAmount(salesBillingForm).toFixed(2)}}</td>--> </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: my html code is : billing.component.html
<tbody *ngFor="let row of SalesBilling">
                    <tr style="background:#eceaea">
                        <td align="right">{{row.NetAmount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
                        <td align="right">{{row.VATAmount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
                        <td align="right">{{row.GrandAmount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
<!--                        <td align="right">{{calculateGrandAmount(salesBillingForm).toFixed(2)}}</td>-->
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: Create another field in the salesBilling array and insert the total there... On HTML, just print that field... It's not like you're taking the input of these fields, in which case tie the change event to calculating this total for that particular row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `row` from the HTML, using `<td>{{functionName(row)}}` and calculate the value in the ts function:

```
functionName(row){
    //Calculate and return some value
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.